# Android Countdown Timer save

Tags: java, android

i want the user to wait 12h before he can use something again. 
I want to take into account how much time remained even if the user exit the application. I am using countdown time and i do not really know how to do this. This is the code i am using

```
new CountDownTimer(43200000, 1000) {

    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
        timer1.setText("" + String.format(FORMAT,
            TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(millisUntilFinished),
            TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millisUntilFinished) - TimeUnit.HOURS.toMinutes(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(millisUntilFinished)),
            TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(millisUntilFinished) - TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millisUntilFinished))));
    }

    public void onFinish() {
        timer1.setText("00:00:00");
    }
}.start();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the user performs the action, save the current time in `SharedPreferences` using `System.currentTimeMillis()`. When the user tries this action again, do `System.currentTimeMillis() - <the previously recorded time from SharedPrefs>` and check to see if this is less than 4.32e+7 (12 hours in milliseconds). If it is less, then deny access to the function.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Awesome! Please accept the answer. Glad I could help